# How can check a php file is successfully included?

Tags: php, include

I want to check if 'dbas.php' is included in 'ad.php'. I wrote the code -

***ad.php***

```
<?php if(file_exists("dbas.php") && include("dbas.php")){
// some code will be here
}
else{echo"Database loading failed";}
?>
```

I successfully tested the file_exists() part but don't know if the include() will work well or not, cause I tried in localhost and if the file is in directory then it never fails to include. So I don't know how this code would behave in the server if much traffic  be there. So please tell me is my code correct ?

-Thanks.

***Solved:*** Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: You can test it by making the `dbas.php` file not-readable by the webserver. It will assert it exists, but cannot include it.

Comment: not use your code bcoz in your code when file is not found it shows php errors and that is bad you can use below i have post code

Comment: that wouldn't throw any error if the file not found in directory.If the file in the directory, only then the following code will run,otherwise will show "Database loading failed".thats why I used file_exists() to check if the file is in directory.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using php's [`require` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) is more suitable if you want to be absolutely sure that the file is included. [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) only checks if the file exists, not if it's actually readable.

`require` will produce an error if inclusion fails (you can `catch` the error, see Cerbrus' answer).

Edit:

However, if you don't want the script to halt if the inclusion fails, use the method `is_readable` along with `file_exists`, like:

```
if( file_exists("dbas.php") && is_readable("dbas.php") && include("dbas.php")) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: The OP seems to be able to want to catch the error. So `require` is perhaps not the best idea?

Comment: Yes, I liked" if( file_exists("dbas.php") && is_readable("dbas.php") && include("dbas.php")) { /* do stuff */ } "this code .Thanks for your help.

Comment: See @Cerbrus answer for an example using `try/catch`.

Comment: Sorry, this is bad advice that only works in certain specific cases! There's a much more serious problem with `file_exists` than just it "only checks if the file exists, not if it's actually readable": `include` will look for scripts at various, sometimes nontrivial places (like not even looking in "./", or other files elsewhere taking precedence, despite one existing in "./"), which `file_exists` will, of course, never do. So, unless you reimplement PHP's own built-in lookup logic for script inclusion, your only option is, frankly, intercepting the PHP error.

Comment: Another serious inconsistency that needs to be made explicit: `file_exists("dbas.php")` looks in the *current directory*, i.e. the one you get with `getcwd`. OTOH, `include("dbas.php")` is only guaranteed to find the file in the *current script's own directory* (i.e. `__DIR__`), which may very well not be the same as that other one. (Mind you, `include_path` often includes ".", and often as the first entry, so people may continue to get away with sloppyness like this, without even knowing about the landmines...)

Answer (score 7):

Simply use `require`:

```
try {
    require 'filename.php';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Require failed! Error: '.$e);
    // Or handle $e some other way instead of `exit`-ing, if you wish.
}
```

Something that wasn't mentioned yet: you *could* add a boolean, like:

```
$dbasIncluded = true;
```

In your `dbas.php` file, then check for that boolean in your code. Although generally, if a file doesn't include properly, you'd want php to hit the brakes, instead of rendering the rest of the page.

Comment: +1 because it does not repeat the file name, as in other replies.

Comment: But this doesn't work, does it ? Require throws fatal error, which can't be catch with try/catch.

Comment: As Frodik says: require throws fatal error, which cannot be catched. Instead you can use include, which merely emits a warning. You can register an error handler with set_error_handler to look for the warning. But it will be easier to check for a function or class that is supposed to exist in the file included, as suggested by Bart.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists("dbas.php")` Is doing the checking. If it exists, then do the include.

```
if(file_exists("dbas.php"){
    include("dbas.php")
    //continue with you code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your functionality in a function and use [`function_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if it is there.

```
include ("php_file_with_fcn.php");
if (function_exists("myFunc")) {
    myFunc();
    // run code
} else {
    echo "failed to load";
}
```

In your case, the incusion file would be

```
function db_connect() {
     $user = "user";
     $pass = "pass";
     $host = "host";
     $database = "database";
     mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
     return mysql_select_db($database);
}
```

and the main file:

```
include("db_connect.php");
if (function_exists("db_connect")) {
    if (db_connect() === TRUE) {
        // continue
     } else {
        // failed to connect (this is a different error than the "can't include" one and 
        // actually **way** more important to handle gracefully under great load
     }
 } else {
     // couldn't load database code
 }
```

Comment: I've got an idea from your code, I would initial a variable in dbas.php file and will check in ad.php if the value is correct. then would be sure if the dbas.php is successfully included or not. $i=100;// I would add this line to dbas.php. and will check that in ad.php <?php $i=""; include("dbas.php"); if($i==100){echo"connection ok;"}else{echo"connection failed";}?> How about this ?

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that. I would put your database connection code in a function, check its existence and call it. You would then also be able to handle the connection failure a lot more graceful than `echo`-ing or (the horror!) `die`.

Comment: If the `include("php_file_with_fcn.php");` fails, you won't have to check if the function exists, because your page will return a error on the include.
Why check if it exists, if it can't "not" exist, when the include happens?

Comment: @Cerbrus: we are talking about high-load problems, not existence problems (I seem to understand). IMHO, you should put only functions / classes in include files and not actual page logic. It makes the page-generating PHP file a lot more readable. Compare with functions have side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of your code, because in your code if file is not exist in server then php errors arise and that is not good so use this code:

```
if(file_exists("dbas.php")) {
    include_once("dbas.php");
} else {
    echo"file is not found";
}
```

This code means if file exists on server then function include else file is not found `echo`.

Comment: _"then php errors arise and that is not good"_ What do you mean by that?
php errors are better than echo-ing that a file is not found, since there's generally more information in the error.

Comment: yes i am totally agree with you but in ux that is not good that's why am saying

Answer (score -2):

write

```
echo "file is includ"
```

at the end of "dbas.php"

Comment: my 'dbas.php' code is <?php
$host="localhost";       
$dbname="store"; 
$username="";            
$password="";
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or DIE('cannot connect');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('cannot select db');
?> So when the file is incuded then database code is active on the page. I want to know that is my code correct to check the file inclusion if much traffic be in server.(Im not sure about that cause I checked in localhost only.so don't know is it ok for much traffic server or not.)